# Android Studio freezes after update from 0.4.3 to 0.4.4

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze, android-gradle-plugin

Updated Android Studio and now after restart it freezes while loading my project.

Environment:

- `OSX 10.9.1`
- Android Studio (Preview) `0.4.4`
- Android Studio `idea.vmoptions` has `-Xmx1750m`
- java version "1.7.0_51"
- Gradle `1.9`
- Android SDK Tools Rev. `22.3`
- Android SDK Build-tools rev. `19.0.1` (although some included libs uses `19.0.0`, so those are also there)

While loading stucks and shows `1 process running...` and in `Background Tasks` list there's `Refreshing 'my-project' Gradle project`.

Added few comments in G+ Community's related posts:

- https://plus.google.com/111995766440499916212/posts/TowGyFEi2Am
- https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/DdXq5WuxPVj
- https://plus.google.com/+BoguslawBuszydlik/posts/Eoyvv4NxuNM

To summarise, tried, but none of those helped:

- adb restart;
- android sdk update;
- removing .idea folder;
- reimporting project;
- updating all libs to use latest build-tools `19.0.1`
- increase memory allowances to `-Xms521m -Xmx2750m`
- Updating Gradle to `1.10`
- Restarting laptop

Note, another project loads successfully. I just need to close this project's loading and open another project.

Still looking how to fix this.

Comment: For one, you should be using Gradle 1.10 and v0.8 of the Android Gradle plugin. But what are the two processes that are running?

Comment: IDE is stuck, so I can't check. How could I find that? Logs?

Comment: If the IDE is really completely frozen, then it probably needs more RAM. If it's still operational but just working endlessly, you should be able to click on the "2 processes running" text to bring up a window that shows what those processes are.

Comment: I rolled back to 0.4.3 because 0.4.4 doesn't want to sync my project with gradle.

Comment: Machine has 8GB RAM. Will check once again if java `XMX` parameter isn't resetted after update, because I remember I was giving it maybe 1.5GB of RAM before or more.

Comment: idea.vmoptions has -Xmx1750m

Comment: After updating to `Gradle 1.10` was loading project longer, but still freezed.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back to [Android Studio 0.4.2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) helped for now.